# How can i make the lines to move smooth to the right when padding the lines with numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void AddNumbersToLines(RichTextBox Rchtxt, int PadValue)
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            padnumbers = new List<string>();
            lines = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                string padnumber = (i + 1).ToString("D" + PadValue);
                padnumbers.Add(padnumber);

                lines[i] = padnumber + " " + oldlines[i];
            }
            Rchtxt.Lines = lines.ToArray();
        }
```

Coloring the numbers only

```
private void RichTextboxColorFirstLetter(RichTextBox Rchtxt, Color color)
        {
            if (padnumbers.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < padnumbers.Count; i++)
                {
                    string text = Rchtxt.Lines[i].Substring(0, padnumbers[i].Length);
                    Rchtxt.Select(Rchtxt.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i), text.Length);
                    Rchtxt.SelectionColor = color;
                }
            }
        }
```

numericupdown event

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddNumbersToLines(richTextBox1, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);

            richTextBox1.SelectAll();
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            RichTextboxColorFirstLetter(richTextBox1, Color.Red);
        }
```

In the constructor

```
oldlines = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList();
AddNumbersToLines(richTextBox1, 5);
RichTextboxColorFirstLetter(richTextBox1, Color.Red);
```

oldlines and padnumbers are List type

There are two problems.

The first is when i press the numericupdow button to change the value up or down while the program is running not clicking one by one but pressing it nonstop it's padding fine but starting slow and then getting faster and faster. How can i make it smooth to add and pad the numbers fast from the start ?

The second problem is if there are lines for example:

```
001            hello world
```

When i change the value in the numericupdown most of the lines there is one space between the padding number and the text like: 001 Hello
So it will push hello to the right according to the padding number.

```
001 Hello.....0001 Hello.....0001 Hello
```

But if it's like the first example it will be:

```
001            hello world......001           hello world......001          hello world
```

And it will not push the hello world until it will finish padding all the spaces like so:

```
      001      hello world......001           hello world......001
```

I need somehow to find how many spaces there are between the padding numbers and the text in each line and keep adding the same amount of spaces each time changing the numericupdown value. But not sure how to do it.

Comment: I recorded a very short video showing the problems https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOZ2RWY673Q&feature=youtu.be

Comment: It looks like the spacing is being done by a tab character which will align it to a boundary. This would keep it in one spot until it shifts. You would either need to replace TAB (char(7)) characters with spaces.